# Order of automorphism group of an almost elementary abelian group

Tags: finite-groups

Let $A$ be an almost elementary  abelian 2-group with an elementary abelian subgroup $B$ of index 2. If $|B|=2^m$ then what can we say about the order of automorphism group of $A$?

Comment: Note that all such $A$ can be constructed via an automorphism of order 2 of $B$, and letting this element square to a fixed point in $B$. I'll try and say more when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this but here goes:  We know any automorphism of $A$ must restrict to an automorphism of $B$, and  $Aut(B) = GL(m,2)$. Also, there is a unique nonzero element of $A$ that is in the image of the map $x \rightarrow 2x$.  This element must get mapped to itself. So with a suitable basis any automorphism of $A$ restricts to the subgroup of $GL(m,2)$ with the first column $(1,0,0,...0)^t$. This subgroup has size $(2^m-2)(2^m-4)...(2^m-2^{m-1})$. Now in order to extend one of these suitable $B$-automorphisms to an $A$-automorphism it is enough to specify where one of the elements of order 4 goes, there are $2^m$ choices. So I'm getting $|Aut(A)|=(2^m-2)(2^m-4)...(2^m-2^{m-1})2^m$.

Comment: Is it obvious that $B$ is characteristic?

Comment: But in a special case, $A$ can be an elementary abelian group of order $2^{m+1}$...

Comment: Try this reasoning with $A=D_8$ to see what goes wrong.